# Change column header depending on marked row on Spotfire

Tags: r, spotfire, tibco

I have two cross tables on a single page.

The first cross table is a summary that has Components on the horizontal axis, and Facilities on the vertical axis. The cell values shows colors "RED", "YELLOW", or "NA". The second cross table is a drilldown of the marked row on the summary table, with the horizontal axis Components and Type on the vertical axis. The cell values are a count function.

What I need is to have the color of what I marked show below each component in the drilldown.

```
Summary
+----------+--------+-------+--------+
| Facility | COMP1  | COMP2 | COMP3  |
+----------+--------+-------+--------+
| FAC1     | NA     | RED   | RED    |
| FAC2     | YELLOW | NA    | RED    |
| FAC3     | RED    | RED   | YELLOW |
+----------+--------+-------+--------+


Drilldown (If I mark the FAC2 row)
+-------+--------+-------+
| Type  | COMP1  | COMP3 |
+       + YELLOW +  RED  +
|-------|--------|-------|
| TYPE1 | 12     |       |
| TYPE2 | 11     | 4     |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

Does anyone know if this is possible with cross tables? Any tips on how to do it? I appreciate the help.

Thanks,
John

Edit: I'm doing this to go around not being able to color column headers of a cross table, so if anyone has an alternative, I would appreciate it.

Currently using Spotfire 7.11

Comment: And if you mark two rows with two different colors, do you want to see both words? I was initially thinking a IPython script but there really isn't anything happening here to trigger it to read. But an IPython script can iterate over the marked rows for a column and read the value, then return it in a Doc Prop used in titles...

Comment: I didn't think of marking two rows, but it would be nice for comparing two facilities. Do you have a reference on how to do the script? The problem with having the values of each column being read then saved into a document property is that currently, there are around 150 components, and there could be more added in the future. I was thinking if it would be possible instead to have a calculated row that have the colors of what I chose, but idk how to do it yet (though, I got a tip to add it in the SQL of my table).

Comment: What if instead of coloring the headers, you colored the background? Also, python can very quickly iterate over thousands of rows and pull out distinct values so the number is not the issue, the issue is you need some action control to tell it to run. Changing markings is not an action, unless we maybe tie it to an R script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Bear with me here as I have hacked together a solution. I will say, I made some assumptions about your data structure. Depending on the structure of your data, the answer may need slightly modified.

Here is the structure of my data:

[image]

**Step 1:** Create two document properties to hold the values of the title. I created two document properties named "tableTitle1" and "tableTitle2" (one for each column in the details cross table). Create one document property to hold a DateTime value that an r script will pass us (will discuss later). I named mine "time".

**Step 2:** Create the cross tables as you have them. Ensure the first cross table is using Marking "Marking" and the second is limited by the marking "Marking". In the second cross table, ensure that the titles look something like this: `Count([Comp1]) as [Comp1 ${tableTitle1}], Count([Comp3]) as [Comp2 ${tableTitle2}]`. You need to use the document properties created in Step 1.

**Step 3:** Create the python script. The code is as follows:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

# Create a cursor for the table column to get the values from.
# Add a reference to the data table in the script.
dataTable = Document.Data.Tables["SOTest"]
cursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dataTable.Columns["Comp1"])

# Retrieve the marking selection
markings = Document.Data.Markings["Marking"].GetSelection(dataTable).AsIndexSet()

# Create a List object to store the retrieved data marking selection
markedata = List [str]();

# Iterate through the data table rows to retrieve the marked rows
for row in dataTable.GetRows(markings, cursor):
    value = cursor.CurrentValue
    if value <> str.Empty:
        markedata.Add(value)

# Get only unique values
valData = List [str](set(markedata))

# Store in a document property
Document.Properties["tableTitle1"] = ', '.join(valData)

####DO IT AGAIN FOR THE SECOND COLUMN#####

# Create a cursor for the table column to get the values from.
# Add a reference to the data table in the script.
cursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dataTable.Columns["Comp2"])

# Create a List object to store the retrieved data marking selection
markedata = List [str]();

# Iterate through the data table rows to retrieve the marked rows
for row in dataTable.GetRows(markings, cursor):
    value = cursor.CurrentValue
    if value <> str.Empty:
        markedata.Add(value)

# Get only unique values
valData = List [str](set(markedata))

# Store in a document property
Document.Properties["tableTitle2"] = ', '.join(valData)
```

**Step 4:** Create an R Script to kick off the python script when data is marked. This is going to be a very simple R Script. The code is as follows:

```
markedTable <- inputTable
time <- Sys.time()
```

The check box for allow caching should be unchecked. The output parameter time should go to the document property time. the input parameter inputTable should be your datatable, all columns, and should be limited by Marking. Ensure that the refresh function automatically checkbox is checked.

**Step 5:** Map the python script to the time document property. In the Edit > Document Properties dialogue box, under Properties, assign the python script we created to the document property. The R script will change the current datetime each time the marking on the table changes, thus running our python script for us.

**Step 6:** Watch the magic happen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for answering. I'll be changing it a bit as the count is a column on the table instead of a count of data entries. It'll take a bit of fiddling to work with my data set, but thank you very much!  :)